# Counting a number in LaTeX

Tags: beamer, numbering, enumerate, counters

I have a large LaTeX (`beamer`) document that I am preparing. Within that document, I have several quizzes (poor students!). I want to have some sort of counter that I can add one (1) to it rather than knowing exactly what quiz number it is, when writing new quizzes. For example, can I define a variable and put it equal to 1 and every time I just increment 1? If yes, how exactly?

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\begin{document}  
\frame{\frametitle{Quiz 1}\framesubtitle{}  
\begin{itemize}  
\item  
Questions  
\end{itemize}  
}  
\frame{\frametitle{Quiz 2}\framesubtitle{}    
\begin{itemize}  
\item  
Questions  
\end{itemize}  
}  
\frame{\frametitle{Quiz 3}\framesubtitle{}  
\begin{itemize}  
\item  
Questions  
\end{itemize}  
}  
\end{document}
```

TL;DR: I want to enumerate a number outside `enumerate` environment

Comment: `\newcounter{yournicecounter}` and `\stepcounter{yournicecounter}` .... but your question is not really clear!  Seeing your document would really help and I assume that there is such a counter already.

Comment: ... and in case of references being necessary, use `\refstepcounter{yournicecounter}` rather!

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I have added some code snippet. I hope it is clear now. Thanks.

Comment: We don't prefer code snippets but documents that can be compiled  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the 'snippet' and defined a `quiznumber` counter.

With `\pretocmd{\frame}{\stepcounter{quiznumber}}{}{}` it is possible to allow an automatic increase of this counter.

Using the `framenumber` counter would be possible too, but there might be frames that do not contain quizzes.

Of course, if there are intermediate frames without quizzes, the number would not be correct, of course.

In this case, just reset or adapt the quiznumber with `\setcounter{quiznumber}{some value}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{quiznumber}

\pretocmd{\frame}{\stepcounter{quiznumber}}{}{}

\begin{document}



\frame{\frametitle{Quiz \thequiznumber}\framesubtitle{}  
Questions here  
}  
\frame{\frametitle{Quiz \thequiznumber}\framesubtitle{}  
Questions here  
}  

\frame{\frametitle{Quiz \thequiznumber}\framesubtitle{}  
Questions here  
}  

\frame{\frametitle{Quiz \thequiznumber}\framesubtitle{}  
Questions here  
}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: If references should be used, then replace `\stepcounter` by `\refstepcounter`